# Maclaurin of $(x^2+x+1)^{-1}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Good day!

I stumbled upon this question on Maclaurin series which puzzled me quite a bit.

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$ and that it can be represented by
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_nx^n}.$$
Find the value of $c_{36} - c_{37} + c_{38}.$

**My approach:**

The General formula for $\frac{1}{1+x} $ is $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4+\cdots$ Now, we can complete the square to form
$$\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)+1}\right)$$
and replace the $x$ with $\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}+ \frac {1} {\sqrt3}\right)$ but this is very tedious and complicated.

**Alternate approach:**

Differentiate $f(x)$ many times to get general formula for $$f(0)+f^1(0)+f^2(0)+... +f^n(0).$$

Likewise the differentiation gets really messy and complicated very quickly and that the expansion does not seem to follow a general $1+1+1+1$ or $1-1+1-1$ coefficient pattern. How would one tackle this question in the most efficient way?

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = \frac{1 - x}{1 - x^3}$.

Comment: Unimaginably simple @TheoBendit

Comment: @TheoBendit damn how did u see that identity I have not come across that before or maybe i just dont have enough practice. By that expression I will expand $(1-x) \frac {1} {1-x^3}$ to get $x^{36} - x^{37} + 0x^{38}$ hence answer is 1-(-1) = 2

Comment: @NgJunWei It's just the (finite) geometric sum identity:$$1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}.$$Give it time. Eventually you too will have an instant association between $1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n$ and $1 - x^{n+1}$.